# Spring 6 - How does injection work with tests?

Tags: spring, junit

I'm trying to create a test (JUnit 5) in my Spring 6 (without boot) project and I need to inject my repository to use it for tests:

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class TestMessageRepository {

    @Autowired
    private CrudRepository<Message, Long> messageRepository ;

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void testFindAllEmpty() {
        assertFalse(messageRepository.findAll().iterator().hasNext());
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

`Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findAll()" because "this.messageRepository" is null`

I feel like my question is very triviel but I'm just discovering Spring and IoC in general and it's not very clear to me how everyting works yet.

Comment: duplicated question. please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168503/339637