# How to "Autowire" repository in JUnit 5 test

Tags: spring, junit5, spring-test

I don't understand yow to refer to my services/repositories in a JUnit 5 test. I'm trying to annotate it the same as I do my Main class which runs fine:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class TestMessageRepository {
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void testFindAllEmpty() {
        assertFalse(messageRepository.findAll().iterator().hasNext());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when I run the test class I got an error `Cannot invoke "com.cypherf.repository.MessageRepository.findAll()" because "this.messageRepository" is null`. So how are you supposed to do it?

In my main class I have a static main method which instantiates an ApplicationContext then uses it to create a bean and run it:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class TestSpringApplication {
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestSpringApplication.class);
        TestSpringApplication app = ctx.getBean(TestSpringApplication.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Isthat what I am supposed to do in every test class?

Comment: Provided you have spring-boot, replace the annotations on your Test class with `@DataJpaTest` to instantiate the context with jpa related beans. `@ComponentScan` without a value won't do anything btw

Comment: he is not using spring-boot , just pure spring as far as i know from his bunch of questions recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , you have to use [`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/support-classes.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-extension) to integrate spring testing framework with Junit5.

Second , you have to use [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/annotations/integration-spring/annotation-contextconfiguration.html) to tell spring what are the configuration classes to use to bootstrap the spring context.

Not guarantee it would solve all your problems , but combining these two should make your test at least can bootstrap the spring context and autowire `MessageRepository` into the test class :

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= TestSpringApplication.class)
class TestMessageRepository {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Test
    void testFindAllEmpty() {
        assertFalse(messageRepository.findAll().iterator().hasNext());
    }
}
```